# Making "showModalBottomSheet" animate downwards in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

In the following code, there is "GestureDetector" inside "showModalBottomSheet", I want the "showModalBottomSheet" to animate downward after "loadingIndicator(context);" disappears and before triggering "Get.to( () => const LoadingScreen(),);".

```
Future<dynamic> chooseDeliveryLocation(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          height: size.height * 0.45,
          width: size.width,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Choose delivery location',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const DeliveryLocation(
                  icon: Icons.location_on_outlined,
                  locationDetails:
                      'MVVM stands for Model-View-ViewModel. The basic idea is to create.',
                  locationName: 'Home',
                ),
                locationDetection(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                    onTap: () async {
                      loadingIndicator(context);
                      await Future.delayed(
                        const Duration(seconds: 3),
                        () => PageRouteBuilder(
                          pageBuilder: 
                        ),
                      );

                      Get.to(
                        () => const LoadingScreen(),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Obx(
                      () => DeliveryLocation(
                        icon: Icons.my_location,
                        locationName: 'Deliver to current location',
                        locationDetails:
                            locationController.deliveryLocation2.value,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                          width: 20,
                          child: isDetectingLocation
                              ? Transform.translate(
                                  offset: const Offset(-4, -1),
                                  child: circularProgressIndicator(2),
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const DeliveryLocation(
                  icon: Icons.pin_drop_outlined,
                  locationDetails:
                      'MVVM stands for Model-View-ViewModel. The basic idea is to create.',
                  locationName: 'Deliver to different location',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

I tried many times to do it but with no luck as I'm still learning

Comment: Have you tried `Get.back()` after `loadingIndicator(context);`? `Get.back()` will close current overlay if present.

Comment: No but i will try it, what about the animation of showModalBottomSheet?